# Sed using in logfiles

Tags: unix, sed, awk, command, match

The original logfile sample:

"GET /dynamic_preroll_playlist.fmil?domain=13nwuc&width=480&height=360&imu=medrect&pubchannel=filmannex&ad_unit=category_2&sdk_ver=2.4.1.3&embeddedIn=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.filmannex.com%2Fmovie%2Fend-of-the-tunnel%2F20872&sdk_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic2.filmannex.com%2Fflash%2F&**viewport=10,261,971,0,971,0,10,261** HTTP/1.1", 200, 201, 1516, 16363, "http://static2.filmannex.com/flash/yume_ad_library.swf", pl.networks.com, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; FunWebProducts; GTB7.3; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; FunWebProducts; .NET4.0C)", "24_100_150_188_jZKFKQQjdRNM6e", "0rO0ABXd8AAAACgAAASQAAAaLAAAGiwAAASgAAAaLAAAGiwAAAVoAAAaLAAAGiwAAAVkAAAaKAAAGiwAAAdwAAAaKAAAGiwAAAhIAAAaKAAAGiwAAAhUAAAaKAAAGiwAAAhYAAAaKAAAGiwAAAhsAAAaKAAAGiwAAAiwAAAaKAAAGiw**", "-", "-", "@YD_1;233_2739", -, "-", "24.100.150.188", "199.127.205.6"

The required output is the 3rd and 4th field of viewport:

```
971 0
```

I used the command:

```
sed -n 's/.*viewport=\([^&]*\)/\1 /p' filename
```

get the wrong output : `10,261,971,0,971,0,10,261** HTTP/1.1", 200, 201, 1516, 16363, .....` too much redundant info following it.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Use the sed command fetch the 3rd and 4th parameter of  viewport?

Thanks so much in advance :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use awk

```
gawk 'match($0, /&viewport=[0-9]+,[0-9]+,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)/, m){print m[1], m[2]}'
```

Note: Third argument to `match` is available only in `gawk`, so this script is gawk-specific.
Explanation: we provide regex to `match` function, which captures third and fourth field in `viewport`. `match` returns non-zero value if provided regex can be successfully matched against some substring of whole record.
Then it just prints captured groups.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not familiar with the syntex you wrote. What if I wanna get the 5th and 6th field in viewport? how to change the gawk command?

Comment: I hope you know he literally just captured the 3rd and 4th groups by writing out #,#,(#),(#) explicitly.

Comment: Yes, twmb is correct. Just write explicitly #,#,#,#,(#),(#). Not a very flexible approach, but suitable for most daily things.

Answer (score 2):

You stripped the right field, now feed the output to another tool:

```
sed ...... | awk -F, '{print $3, $4}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Or if you want to use grep and cut (hey, not everything has sed and awk):

```
grep -o "&viewport=[0-9,]*" filename | grep -o "[0-9,]*" | cut -d "," -f 3,4
```

Or you could use your previous command and pass that off to the same cut.

```
sed -n 's/.*viewport=\([^&]*\) /\1/p' sedtest | cut -d "," -f 3,4
```

Also, the reason it captures the rest of your text is because you substitute everything at the beginning with just the numbers, while leaving everything at the end.  If you want to capture *just* the viewport parameters, you need substitute the entire string, not just the beginning.  Also throw a space in the negated character set to stop after it.

```
sed -n 's/.*viewport=\([^& ]*\).*/\1/p' sedtest
```

With which you can do what I said before (though you don't need this latest addition).

Answer (score 1):

One way using `grep`, `perl` regex and `awk` in a pipe:

```
< file.txt grep -oP "viewport=[^ ]+" | awk -F "[=,]" '{ print $3, $4 }'
```

One way using `awk`:

```
awk -v RS="viewport=[^ ]+" 'RT != "" { split (RT,array,"[=,]"); print array[1 + 3], array[1 + 4] }' file.txt
```

**EDIT:**

In the `awk` only solution, I made it easier to select the viewport fields of interest. If you would like the 5th and 6th fields, simply change the `array[1 + 3], array[1 + 4]` to `array[1 + 5], array[1 + 6]`. Also, these solutions have the added advantage of finding multiple occurrences per line.

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`-only solution:

```
awk '{split($0,a,"viewport=");split(a[2],b,",");print b[3],b[4]}' filename
```

yields

```
971 0
```

This splits the input line using the string `"viewport="` into an array named `a`, and takes the  element of the array `a` that contains the data *after* `"viewport="` and splits it into array `b`, and then prints out the elements we are interested in.