# gawk command in matching data

Tags: unix, sed, command, gawk

The original logfile sample:

> "GET
>   /dynamic_preroll_playlist.fmil?domain=13nwuc&width=480&height=360&imu=medrect&pubchannel=filmannex&ad_unit=category_2&sdk_ver=2.4.1.3&embeddedIn=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.filmannex.com%2Fmovie%2Fend-of-the-tunnel%2F20872&sdk_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic2.filmannex.com%2Fflash%2F&**viewport=10,261,971,0,981,10,10,261**
>   HTTP/1.1", 200, 201, 1516, 16363,
>   "http://static2.filmannex.com/flash/yume_ad_library.swf",
>   pl.networks.com, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0;
>   FunWebProducts; GTB7.3; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729;
>   .NET CLR 3.0.30618; FunWebProducts; .NET4.0C)",
>   "24_100_150_188_jZKFKQQjdRNM6e",
>   "0rO0ABXd8AAAACgAAASQAAAaLAAAGiwAAASgAAAaLAAAGiwAAAVoAAAaLAAAGiwAAAVkAAAaKAAAGiwAAAdwAAAaKAAAGiwAAAhIAAAaKAAAGiwAAAhUAAAaKAAAGiwAAAhYAAAaKAAAGiwAAAhsAAAaKAAAGiwAAAiwAAAaKAAAGiw**",
>   "-", "-", "@YD_1;233_2739", -, "-", "24.100.150.188", "199.127.205.6"

The required output is the 5rd and 6th field of viewport:

981 10

I got the gawk code below which yields  the 3rd and 4th fields:

910 0

```
gawk 'match($0, /&viewport=[0-9]+,[0-9]+,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)/, m){print m[1], m[2]}' filename
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? Just a little change to the gawk command fetch the 5th and 6th parameters of viewport?

Any ideas? Thanks so much in advance :)

Comment: Do a simple formatting to make your question readable. [Editing-tips](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @mtk - I see why he hasn't done that.  He is highlighting the relevant part of his string using boldface, which can't be done within a <code> block.

Comment: @ghoti Still a formatting is possible. Have placed an edit in the queue, will hopefully appear soon.

Comment: Exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855237/sed-using-in-logfiles

Comment: Why do you get 910 instead of 971 from the sample data?  Surely, the extension from fields 3 & 4 to fields 5 & 6 is pretty much automatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this command will do what you want:

```
awk '{split($0,a,"viewport=");split(a[2],b,",");print b[5],b[6]}' filename
```

gives:

```
981 10
```

***If*** *you do want the modified `gawk` command*:

```
gawk 'match($0, /&viewport=[0-9]+,[0-9]+,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)/, m){print m[3], m[4]}' filename
```

will also work.

I think the first solution is cleaner/clearer and also easier to modify.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*&viewport=\(\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\)\{3\}.*/\2 \3/' file
```